# Unable to link dynamic library in macOS

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I'm trying to use a C library called [quirc](https://github.com/dlbeer/quirc) in my C project. So far, I have generated a `libquirc.dylib.1.0` by modifying the `Makefile` which was using Linux `.so` files.

**quirc/helloquirc.c**

```
#include <quirc.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {

    struct quirc *qr;

    qr = quirc_new();

    if (!qr) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory");
    }

    quirc_destroy(qr);

    return 0;
}
```

I've created the above source file at the root of the repository. I'm using the following command to compile it:

```
gcc helloquirc.c -lquirc -L. -Ilib -o helloquirc
```

To my understanding the `-l` flag specifies the name of the dynamic library, the `-L` flag specifies the location of the dynamic library, the `-I` flag specifies the location of the header files, and `-o` specifies the name of the executable.

When I run this command I get the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lquirc
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I changed the `Makefile` by using this line

```
.PHONY: libquirc.dylib
libquirc.dylib: libquirc.$(LIB_VERSION).dylib

libquirc.$(LIB_VERSION).dylib: $(LIB_OBJ)
    $(CC) -shared -dynamiclib -o $@ $(LIB_OBJ) $(LDFLAGS) -lm
```

and changing other instances of `.so.$(LIB_VERSION)` to `.$(LIB_VERSION).dylib`

Comment: Does `libquirc.dylib.1.0` exist in the same directory as `helloquirc.c`? Have you tried putting the `-L.` flag *before* the `-lquirc` flag?

Comment: @Evert yes to both questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with the way `quirc` was built.  The correct library name would be something like `libquirc.1.0.dylib` with a symlink named `libquirc.dylib`.

It looks like quirc has a handwritten makefile instead of using something sensible like gyp or cmake.  Handwritten makefiles are just fine as long as you're not trying to build shared libraries on multiple platforms.

However, if you are just compiling it yourself, you may find things simpler if you just use a static library instead.  There is no point in having a shared library if you are not sharing it with anybody (if no other programs are using the *same exact copy* of `libquirc`).

Comment: I changed the `Makefile` to generate `libquirc.1.0.dylib` instead by changing the lines in the updated post

still the same issue. I will definitely consider making it a static library but I would also like to figure this issue out

Comment: Did you make the symlink?  The linker is looking for ordinary `libquirc.dylib` and it has no idea that you actually are looking for `libquirc.1.0.dylib` or `libquirc.dylib.1.0` or `something_else_entirely.dylib`.

Comment: @Carpetfizz: Remember you can just pass the library to the linker as a file, instead of using `-lmylib -Ldir` you can just pass `dir/libmylib.a` or whatever.

Comment: Creating the symlink seems to have done the trick thanks! Do you mind printing the full command of the last thing you said ?

Comment: Instead of `gcc helloquirc.c -lquirc -L. -Ilib -o helloquirc` you could use `gcc helloquirc.c libquirc.1.0.dylib -o helloquirc`

Comment: Also, I briefly looked into creating a static library and seems as though the `.dylib` I have isn't any good for that? I don' t know enough about Makefiles to go through the existing one and convert it to give me a static library as the output

Comment: Ah neat, so it's a shortcut that does the same thing, thanks

Comment: @Carpetfizz: The makefile already has `libquirc.a` as a target.  That's the static library.  Also note that you're not using `gcc`, you can just use `cc`.

Comment: Ah okay, so I generated that - how do I tell `cc` to link it as a static library? Can I use the same command I've been using but provide the `.a` suffix?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Comment: `ld: library not found for -lquirc.a` even though that file exists in my current working directory

Comment: To clarify: the syntax is the same both ways.  You either use `-lquirc -L.` or you use `libquirc.a`.  You can't mix and match.

Comment: So running `gcc helloquirc.c libquirc.a -o helloquirc` resulted in `fatal error: 'quirc.h' file not found`

Comment: Oh never mind `gcc helloquirc.c -I../quirc/lib ../quirc/libquirc.a -o helloquirc` worked!